# Unable to set UserInfo on UNMutableNotificationContent

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to create a location notification that must contains custom data.

My choice would be to use the UserInfo dictionary, but unfortunately I seems that I can't set it.

My code is the following:

```
var content = new UNMutableNotificationContent();
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value: notification.SoundFile))
{
    content.Sound = UNNotificationSound.GetCriticalSound(notification.SoundFile);
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(notification.ChannelDescription))
{
    content.ThreadIdentifier = notification.ChannelDescription;
}

content.Title = notification.Title;
content.Body = notification.Text;
content.CategoryIdentifier = "scheduled-alert";

// The crash occurs on the following line.
content.UserInfo = NSDictionary.FromObjectAndKey(new NSString("remainingTime"), new NSNumber((float)notification.Progress / 100f));
```

The exception is:

```
System.NotSupportedException

StackTrace  "  at Foundation.NSDictionary.set_Item (System.String key, Foundation.NSObject value) [0x00000] 
in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/16.2.0.6/src/Xamarin.iOS/Foundation/NSDictionary.cs:376 \n  at …"
```

Any Idea how to set this property? I've seen that it should be doable according to the apple doc.

Comment: You can refer to the official document: [Triggering a Service Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/enhanced-user-notifications?tabs=macos#triggering-a-service-extension), where UserInfo is used in the case.

Comment: This use case is about reading a value, no setting it.

Comment: Did the reference thread ["Xamarin IOS - UserInfo custom data dictionary is always empty"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63052370/xamarin-ios-userinfo-custom-data-dictionary-is-always-empty) help you?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using this constructor:

```
content.UserInfo = new NSDictionary(new NSString("remainingTime"), new NSNumber(100f));
```